# Separate networks in rooms connected to one router

Tags: nas, home-networking, switch, subnet

I have a problem to solve with network at my home.
I have a central router with address 192.168.1.1 it assigns automatically addresses 192.168.1.* ( I cannot change that) In my room I would like to have a network where all the devices connected would have addresses 192.168.0.* like NAS, printer, raspberry pi etc.
The only requirement is that when I am connected via WIFI to router I can easily access e.g. NAS server by 192.168.0.5. If I knew how to do this I will do another room with 192.168.2.* :)

I have found switch TL-SG108E, will I be able to achieve such a scenario?
If not what would be the best and not expensive?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Your router is probably using DHCP and your connected hosts are sending DHCP requests to this router. Therefore, they a forced to use some parts of the response from the router: the assigned IP address, the netmask and the address of the default router to use. Only when the router is configurable to define and to use different networks, then you can use them. What do you expect as advantage of a subdivision of the network in subnetworks in this environment ?

Comment: In your router’s web interface, can you set up static routes? (Also, why bother with separate networks? Security?)

Comment: If you can't configure the central router, you will need a secondary router for each sub-net.

Comment: I have at least 5 devices to connect by RJ45, so I was thinking that maybe I could have separate addresses for them, but maybe it does not make sense

Comment: The problem is if I have everything connected to one point (router) in case of failure I have no access to my local devices in room. If I have my own router in room if central router fails at least I have connection to NAS. Am I right?